# SwipeRefreshLayout or ProgressBar at first time data load

Tags: android, material-design, android-progressbar, swiperefreshlayout

I'm currently using `SwipeRefreshLayout` with `RecyclerView` in my app. Everything works ok.

What I'm not sure about is when first time data-load at the screen, should I use **circular Loading Indicator** of `SwipeRefreshLayout` like the following.

```
swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override public void run() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
     }
});
```

Or should I use particular `ProgressBar` for **circular Loading Indicator** like the following.

```
private ProgressBar spinner;

spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Which approach is more correct accordance to **Google Material Design Guidelines** because they have major visual differences between `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `ProgressBar` indicators. (I've already googled a lot but haven't found the proper answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you should your progressbar for first time data load.

SwipeRefreshLayout is just to be used when you are in same screen and want to check if new data is available or not

Comment: What is your reference?